# aSQLiteManager not recognizing valid SQLite UPDATE statement

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to update an SQLite table with rows for a second identical database copied from another device. The code works fine on SQLite (windows) but the UPDATE statement gives me an error near "FROM" when I try to run the same on an Android mobile with aSQLiteManager. Because the consolidation needs to take place immediately after the start of the race, it would be a lot more convenient to do this onsite with an Android mobile device. Thanks in advance for any advice :-)

```
SQLite Windows (works fine):
ATTACH DATABASE "SuiviCourse2.db" AS d2;
UPDATE main.Coureurs SET TempsPassage = d2.Coureurs.TempsPassage FROM d2.Coureurs WHERE main.Coureurs.Dossard = d2.Coureurs.Dossard AND d2.Coureurs.TempsPassage <> '';
    
aSQLiteManager on Android:
ATTACH DATABASE "/storage/emulated/0/Download/SuiviCourse2.db" AS d2;
UPDATE d2.Coureurs SET Sexe = 'F' WHERE Dossard = 2; (this test works)
(the following doesn't work)
UPDATE main.Coureurs SET TempsPassage = d2.Coureurs.TempsPassage FROM d2.Coureurs WHERE main.Coureurs.Dossard = d2.Coureurs.Dossard AND d2.Coureurs.TempsPassage <> '';
```

Comment: That syntax was added in 3.33; your android system is using an older version of SQLite.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn, that explains it! I just ran SELECT sqlite_version(); on my phone and it's 3.32.2. Would you suggest a way to change my code so that it's compatible with 3.32.2? Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By searching for a few hours through stackoverflow, I found a method to do this without using UPDATE FROM so it could run on Android devices with SQLite versions prior to v3.33:

```
UPDATE Coureurs
SET TempsPassage=(SELECT d2.Coureurs.TempsPassage 
    FROM d2.Coureurs 
    WHERE TempsPassage <> ''
    AND d2.Coureurs.Dossard=main.Coureurs.Dossard);
```